# How to Calculate the conditional probability $P(Z|AB)$ if we know $P(Z)$, $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(Z|A)$, $P(Z|B)$, $P(AB)$

Tags: probability, statistics

How to Calculate the conditional probability  $P(Z|A∩B)$ if we know $P(Z) , P(A) , P(B) , P(Z|A) , P(Z|B)$ and $P(A∩B)$?

Can we extend this expression to $N$ probability variables?

$P(Z|ABC) =\ $? If we have $P(A), P(B), P(C)$ and $P(Z|A) , P(Z|B) , P(Z|C) , P(A∩B) , P(A∩C) , P(B∩C)$?

Here is an explanation to understand what I'm looking for.

You have two weather prophets. They making weather forecasts.
The question is: Will rain fall tomorrow?

P(Z) = The probability of rainy day eg: 160 days is rainy in a year (160 / 365)

P(A) = The probability of Forecaster A saying "It will rain tomorrow.".  (rain forecasts of Forecaster A in a year / 365)

P(B) = The probability of Forecaster B saying "It will rain tomorrow.".  (rain forecasts of Forecaster B in a year / 365)

P(AB) = The probability of  (Forecaster A ) and (Forecaster B) are saying  "It will rain tomorrow." at the same time (eg: there are 50 days in all year when they makes forecasts at the same time)

P(Z|A) = The accuracy of Forecaster A. (Probability of rainy day for tomorrow if Forecaster A is saying "It will rain tomorrow.")

P(Z|B) = The accuracy of Forecaster B. (Probability of rainy day for tomorrow if Forecaster B is saying "It will rain tomorrow.")

**P(Z|A∩B) = ?** What is the probability of rainy day for tomorrow if (Forecaster A ) and (Forecaster B) are saying "It will rain tomorrow." at the same time.

eg:

P(Z|A) = 0.8

P(Z|B) = 0.8

If A=B (The two forecaster always says the same at the same time) --> P(A|B) = P(B|A) = 1 then P(Z|AB) = 0.8 I think it is not a question.

If A and B are independent events --> P(A∩B) = P(A) * P(B) 
then my assumption is that : P(Z|A∩B) > 0.8

Can we proof and calculate or deny this?

[I have created this excel sheet to explain and proof my assumption](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7WhttzJvGldRTFwVjRFVEwyRkE/view?usp=sharing)

[Screenshot from the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnLjU.png)

Comment: Can you show your attempt and tell, where you were stuck ?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ sets? What do you mean by $AB$ then?

Comment: I'm guessing $AB$ is $A\cap B$ since this question is about conditional probabilities and $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.$$

Comment: This is equivalent to asking whether P(A), P(B), P(C), P(AB), P(BC) and P(AC) determine P(ABC). They do not, and counterexamples showing they do not are all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that $AB$ means $A \cap B$, you can't. (Apologies for the bad MSPaint drawing.)

[image: Venn diagram counterexample]

For both pictures, we have $P(Z) = P(A) = P(B) = 0.4$, we have $P(Z | A) = P(Z | B) = 0.5$, and we have $P(AB) = 0.2$. However, $P(Z | AB) = .5$ for the top picture, and $P(Z | AB) = 0$ for the bottom one. Therefore, $P(Z | AB)$ is not a function of the other expressions.

Comment: An additional comment: this question was more interesting than I thought at first glance. It seemed to me like you *should* be able to determine $P(Z | AB)$ based on the other things, but I tried to prove it and was unable to do so, at which point I started hunting for a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Might be I'm wrong , but i think the Venn diagram represent the probability by the size of the area, it is only true if the density is homogeneous in the event space on the Venn diagram.

Comment: There's no general requirement that in a Venn Diagram, probability corresponds to area. Formally, we can just think of the above picture as us imposing a very specific measure on the space depicted. If you prefer, you can draw ten squares of equal size and specify which boxes apply to which events; this depiction will be much harder to visualize, which is why I didn't use it.

Comment: Yes you are right about the Venn Diagram. I extended my initial question with some details and with an excel sheet that tries to proof my assumption.
The excel sheet shows a special case if A and B are independent events P(Z)= 0.5 , P(Z|A) > 0.5 , P(Z|B) > 0.5 Then P(Z|AB) > Max(P(Z|A) , P(Z|B)). What do you think about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think intuitively as well, we can show this:

$p(Z|AB) = \dfrac{P(ZAB)}{P(AB)}$. Now the objective is to write the right hand side of the equality as a function $f(.)$ (probability measure) of all the marginal, and pairwise probabilities $p(Z|A)$ and $P(Z|B)$. Or, simply writing $P(ZAB)=f(P(Z), P(A), P(B), P(A,Z), P(B,Z), P(A,B))$.
But this is not always true, since in general we cannot represent higher order joint probabilities using pairwise and marginal densities, unless the joint probability follows a certain structure that can be factorized into lower order joint probabilities.

Comment: Do you mean you have some solution or formula for this question if the joint probability follows a certain structure that can be factorized into lower order joint probabilities?

Comment: Not a general formula, but for example a Markov Chain, i.e., $A-Z-B$ can be represented using pairwise and marginal probabilities. In particular $P(ZAB)$ can be decomposed to $P(A|Z)P(Z|B)P(B)$, and using Bayes rule, we can convert $P(A|Z)$ to $\dfrac{P(Z|A)P(A)}{P(Z)}$.